# Newline braces mean what in Go?

Tags: go

when writing gin(a go web frame)  code, I found a
piece of code like this:

```
r := gin.New()
apiv1 := r.Group("/api/v1")

{ // don't understand
    apiv1.GET("/tags", v1.GetTags)
    apiv1.POST("/tags", v1.AddTag)
}
```

It's ok and have no warn or error.

But I do don't know what's the **newline braces** mean, or it just has no effect?

Comment: It's just a way of creating an enclosed scope, be it to avoid some naming conflict or grouping code

Comment: See the link for an explanation - in your example it will only impact formatting (as nothing is declared within the block).

Answer (score 1):

[From Go spec docs](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blocks)

> blocks nest and influence scoping